# Boostrap 4 sticky sidebar not working and scrolls with page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to make the right sidebar called "Recent Posts in Category", on [this page](https://www.slashinit.org/posts/understanding-arm-naving-conventions/) as sticky, so that when user scrolls down, it remains fixed.

Since `affix` is dropped in Bootstrap 4, I tried the CSS way and found an [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/eKNROb) which works fine in my browser. I added the following code to my css file:

```
.make-me-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

and the class is added to the html div

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 sidebar make-me-sticky">
```

but I see no effect. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .make-me-sticky {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100vh;
      }
```